# Print nested_exception with no nested_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, try-catch

I'm trying to print nested exceptions using the following example code from [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/nested_exception):

```
void print_exception(const std::exception& e, int level =  0)
{
    std::cerr << std::string(level, ' ') << "exception: " << e.what() << '\n';
    try {
        std::rethrow_if_nested(e);
    } catch(const std::exception& e) {
        print_exception(e, level+1);
    } catch(...) {}
}
```

However, I get an abort if the innermost exception is a `std::nested_exception` rather than a `std::exception` (IE I throw a `std::nested_exception`, catch it, and then apply `print_exception`).

This is a minimal example:

```
int main() {
    try {
        std::throw_with_nested( std::runtime_error("foobar") );
    } catch(const std::exception& e1) {
        std::cerr << e1.what() << std::endl;
        try {
            std::rethrow_if_nested(e1);
        } catch( const std::exception& e2 ) {
            std::cerr << e2.what() << std::endl;
        } catch( ... ) {
        }
    } catch ( ... ) {
    }
}
```

It aborts:

```
foobar
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::_Nested_exception<std::runtime_error>'
  what():  foobar
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/throw_with_nested) for `std::throw_with_nested` states that

> The default constructor of the nested_exception base class calls
>   std::current_exception, capturing the currently handled exception
>   object, if any, in a std::exception_ptr

so I would expect `e1` to derive from `std::nested_exception` but have no `nested_ptr`. Why does `std::rethrow_if_nested` not handle this? What is the best approach for me to handle this case?

Comment: `std::rethrow_if_nested` would call [rethrow_nested](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/nested_exception/rethrow_nested) which call `std::terminate` when there is no `nested_ptr`, you may do the equivalent manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may write something like:

```
// Similar to rethrow_if_nested
// but does nothing instead of calling std::terminate
// when std::nested_exception is nullptr.

template <typename E>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_polymorphic<E>::value>
my_rethrow_if_nested(const E&) {}

template <typename E>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_polymorphic<E>::value>
my_rethrow_if_nested(const E& e)
{
    const auto* p = dynamic_cast<const std::nested_exception*>(std::addressof(e));

    if (p && p->nested_ptr()) {
        p->rethrow_nested();
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f9ca307b63636b64)