# Recover context from exception

Tags: c++, exception

Consider the following resource managing class

```
class FooResouce
    {
    public:
        explicit FooResouce(T arg_to_construct_with)
            {
            m_foo = create_foo_resouce(arg_to_construct_with);
            if(m_foo == nullptr)
                {throw SomeException(get_foo_resource_error(), arg_to_construct_with);}
            }
        // Dtor and move operations
        // Other FooResource interaction methods
    private:
        foo_resource_t* m_foo;
    };
```

Now, when we decide to catch the exception and format an error message, it's easy to know *what* caused the exception at the fundamental level, but we have no information about *where* the exception was triggered in *the upper level*. Here *upper level* refers the function that tried to create a FooResource, or *any function above that stack frame*. How would you add context to the error in case that is needed:

1. Pass some optional context information as an extra argument to the Ctor, which can then be stored in the exception
2. At callsite use a `pushContext` function. This function will store the context using thread-local storage.
3. Catch and rethrow. I think the code would be ugly in this case.

Comment: Maybe the `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` macros for context?

Comment: @TrebuchetMS __FILE__ and __LINE__ is currently not in the context I am interested in

Comment: Maybe `std::nested_exception`? BTW, what's wrong with `__FILE__`, `__LINE__` and debuggers?

Comment: @Hiroki std::nested_exception is same as (3), right? Debuggers? It is not a bug that the resource could not be created.

Comment: @user877329 thx. Ah I see. Your third requirement is 3: **No** catch and rethrow. So do you want to use exceptions for normal (recoverable) code flow?  Exceptions should be reserved for situations which are truly exceptional.

Comment: @Hiroki Recoverable *where*? And there is no other way to fail a ctor, and I do not like to put the resource into an invalid state, which might be a different approach.

Comment: @user877329 *no other way to fail a ctor* : completely agree with you and that is a true exceptional case.

Comment: @user877329 Just because it's not a bug doesn't mean you are banned from spinning up your debugger and using it to trace the execution flow of your program.

Comment: You might want to look at Boost.Exception, which supports adding arbitrary data to exception objects and provides convenient ways to add common things like file and line, error codes, and error message strings.

Answer (score 2):

Although this solution conflicts with your third requirement *3: No Catch and rethrow*, I propose an solution with `std::nested_exception` and macros because this seems to provide a reasonable solution for the current problem at least to me.
I hope this too long answer can help you.

---

### 1. An Error Handling with `std::nested_exception`

---

First, we can recursively nest exceptions using [`std::nested_exception`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/nested_exception).
Roughly speaking, We can add exceptions of arbitrary types to this class by calling `std::throw_with_nested`.
These enables us to carry all information of thrown exceptions with a rather simple code, just throwing each exception by `std::throw_with_nested` in each ellipsis catch handler `catch(…){ }` in *the upper level*.

For instance, following function `h` throws a `std::nested_exception` which aggregates the user-defined exception `SomeException` and `std::runtime_error`:

```
struct SomeException : public std::logic_error {
    SomeException(const std::string& message) : std::logic_error(message) {}
};

[[noreturn]] void f(){
    std::throw_with_nested(SomeException("error."));
}

[[noreturn]] void g()
{
    try {
        f();
    }
    catch (...) {
        std::throw_with_nested(std::runtime_error("Error of f."));
    }
};

[[noreturn]] void h()
{
    try {
        g();
    }
    catch (...) {
        std::throw_with_nested(std::runtime_error("Error of g."));
    }    
}
```

---

**Locating Exceptions (Fundamental Level)**

Replacing all of these `std::throw_with_nested` by the following function `throw_with_nested_wrapper` through the macro `THROW_WITH_NESTED`, we can make records of the file names and the line numbers where exceptions occurred.
As is well known, `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` are pre-defined by C++ standard.
So the macro `THROW_WITH_NESTED` has a key role to add these location information:

```
// "..." are arguments of the ctor of ETYPE
// and the first one must be a string literal.
#define THROW_WITH_NESTED(ETYPE, ...)  \
throw_with_nested_wrapper<ETYPE>(__FILE__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__);

template<typename E, typename ...Args>
[[noreturn]]
void throw_with_nested_wrapper(
    char const* fileName,
    std::size_t line,
    const std::string& message,
    Args&& ...args)
{
    auto info = std::string(fileName)
                         + ", l." + std::to_string(line) + ", " 
                         + message;
    
    std::throw_with_nested(E(info, std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...));
};
```

---

**Locating Exceptions (Upper Level)**

If we have to pick up information about where the exception was triggered in *the upper level*, the following macro `HOOK` reusing the above macro `THROW_WITH_NESTED` would work for us:

```
#define HOOK(OPERATION)                                         \
[&]()                                                           \
{                                                               \
    try{                                                        \
        return OPERATION;                                       \
    }                                                           \
    catch(...){                                                 \
        auto info = std::string(#OPERATION) + ", upper level."; \
        THROW_WITH_NESTED(std::runtime_error, info);            \
    }                                                           \
}()
```

Finally, first three functions `f`, `g` and `h` are rewritten and simplified as follows:

```
[[noreturn]] void f(){
    THROW_WITH_NESTED(SomeException, "SomeException, fundamental level.");
}

void g(){
    HOOK(f());
};

void h(){
    HOOK(g());
}
```

---

**Extracting Error Information**

Extracting all explanatory information of nested exceptions is a simple task.
Passing the caught exception at the most outer try-catch block into the following function `output_exceptions_impl`, we can do it.
Each nested exception can be recursively thrown by [`std::nested_exception::rethrow_nested`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/nested_exception/rethrow_nested).
Since this member function calls `std::terminate` when there is no stored exception, we should apply `dynamic_cast` to avoid it as pointed out in [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40167897/print-nested-exception-with-no-nested-ptr) post:

```
template<typename E>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_polymorphic<E>::value>
rethrow_if_nested_ptr(const E& exception)
{
    const auto *p = 
        dynamic_cast<const std::nested_exception*>(std::addressof(exception));

    if (p && p->nested_ptr()){
        p->rethrow_nested();
    }
}

void output_exceptions_impl(
    const std::exception& exception,
    std::ostream& stream,
    bool isFirstCall = false)
{
    try 
    {
        if (isFirstCall) { throw; }

        stream << exception.what() << std::endl;
        rethrow_if_nested_ptr(exception);
    }
    catch (const std::runtime_error& e) {
        stream << "Runtime error: ";
        output_exceptions_impl(e, stream);
    }
    /* ...add further catch-sections here... */
    catch(...){
        stream << "Unknown Error.";
    }
}
```

BTW, explicit `try-catch` blocks at the most outer places are rather verbose and thus I usually use the following macro proposed in [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561659/how-can-i-abstract-out-a-repeating-try-catch-pattern-in-c) post:

```
#define CATCH_BEGIN          try{
#define CATCH_END(OSTREAM)   } catch(...) { output_exceptions(OSTREAM); }

void output_exceptions(std::ostream& stream)
{
    try {
        throw;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        output_exceptions_impl(e, stream, true);
    }
    catch (...) {
        stream << "Error: Non-STL exceptions." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Then all exceptions thrown from `h` can be traced and printed by the following code.
Inserting the macros `THROW_WITH_NESTED`, `HOOK`, `CATCH_BEGIN` and `CATCH_END` at the right lines of our code, we can locate exceptions in each thread:

```
CATCH_BEGIN // most outer try-catch block in each thread
...

HOOK(h());
...

CATCH_END(std::cout)
```

Then we get the following output where file names and line numbers are just an examples.
All the available information is recorded:

[**DEMO with 2 threads**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lpVzYBpGyBnOzhof)

> Runtime error: prog.cc, l.119, h(), upper level.
>
> Runtime error: prog.cc, l.113, g(), upper level.
>
> Runtime error: prog.cc, l.109, f(), upper level.
>
> Logic error: prog.cc, l.105, SomeException, fundamental level.

---

## 2. In case of `FooResouce`

---

First requirement is

> 1. Pass some optional context information as an extra argument to the Ctor, which can then be stored in the exception

Let us define the following special exception class `SomeException` which contains some optional context information and the member function `getContext` to get it:

```
class SomeException : public std::runtime_error
{
    std::string mContext;
    
public:
    SomeException(
        const std::string& message,
        const std::string& context)
        : std::runtime_error(message), mContext(context)
    {}
    
    const std::string& getContext() const noexcept{
        return mContext;
    }
};
```

Adding a new argument `context` to `FooResouce::FooResouce` and replacing `throw` by `THROW_WITH_NESTED`, we can pass the first requirement within the above error handling framework:

```
class FooResouce
{
public:
    FooResouce(
        T arg_to_construct_with,
        const std::string& context)
    {
        m_foo = create_foo_resouce(arg_to_construct_with);
        if(!m_foo){
            THROW_WITH_NESTED(SomeException, "Ctor failed.", context);
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
};
```

---

Next,

> but we have no information about where the exception was triggered in the upper level. Here upper level refers the function that tried to create a FooResource,

Creating each `FooResource` with `HOOK`, we can get information about where the ctor was failed in the upper level.
The caller side would be as follows.
In this manner, all error information including messages, contexts and their locations would be clarified in each thread.

```
CATCH_BEGIN // most outer try-catch block in each thread
...

auto resource = HOOK(FooResouce(T(), "context"));
...

CATCH_END(std::cout)
```

---

Finally,

> 2. At callsite use a pushContext function. This function will store the context using thread-local storage.

Although I don't know the detail of this requirement, but since we can call  `SomeException::getContext` in `output_exceptions_impl` as follows and get all contexts from every thrown `SomethingExceptions`, I think we can also store them like this:

[**DEMO(my proposal)**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7DJkHEP85PkM29JD)

```
void output_exceptions_impl(
    const std::exception& exception,
    std::ostream& stream,
    bool isFirstCall = false)
{
    ...
    catch (const SomeException& e) { // This section is added.
        stream 
            << "SomeException error: context:" 
            << e.getContext() << ", "; // or pushContext?
        output_exceptions_impl(e, stream);
    }
    ...
}
```